# creating dynamic widget reference

Tags: python, variables, widget

I have a program using GUIZero for my display interface. On this display, I have 30 pushbuttons created. I am trying to find a way to dynamically reference all 30 buttons. Here is the code I "think" I need, but obviously it is not working. Quick background on GUIZero, I create the pushbutton, and then the pushbutton has parameters I can adjust. I am trying to adjust the background of the pushbutton. That looks like {widget}.{parameter} = {value}. I am trying to make the {widget} portion dynamic.

Here is a shortened version of what works:

```
def Clearapp():
     button_0.bg = "light grey"
     button_1.bg = "light grey"
     button_2.bg = "light grey"
     .
     .
     .
     button_29.bg = "light grey"
```

This is what I "think" it should be, but is not working.

```
bit0 = "button_"

def Clearapp():
     global bit0
     for x in range(30):
          btn = bit0+str(x)      # this makes "button_" + {value of x}
          btn.bg = "light grey"
```

I know I have bit0 set as a global variable, and I am doing that because of the structure of what I am doing, I use that string in a lot of different places, and it makes it easier to use and keep my name and syntax correct.

So, the long and short, I am trying to figure out how to combine 2 strings together and then use that string as a reference or pointer to a specific item. As shown above I tried both code versions. The long version works fine. The short version results with the following errors:

> File "/home/pi/Desktop/qc_box_221129a.py", line 50, in Clearapp btn.bg = "light grey" AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bg'

To add some additional clarity:
I want to use the string value in "btn" (the combination of bit0 and x) as a pointer to go to a specific widget.

So in my bottom code, this is the order of operations:

```
`For x in range(30):
    btn = "button_" + x
    btn.bg = {value}

Step 1: x=0
btn = button_ + 0
{use string to address widget} -> insert value of btn into command "btn.bg = {value}"
button_0.bg = {value}

Step 2: x = 1
btn = button_ + 1
button_1.bg = {value}

Step 3: x = 2
btn = button_ + 2
button_2.bg = {value}
.
.
.
Step 30: x = 29
btn = button_ + 29
button_29.bg = {value}`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use the string value in "btn" (the combination of bit0 and x) as a pointer to go to a specific widget.

So in my bottom code, this is the order of operations:
`For x in range(30):
    btn = "button_" + x
    btn.bg = {value}

Step 1: x=0
btn = button_ + 0
{use string to address widget} -> insert value of btn into command "btn.bg = {value}"
button_0.bg = {value}

Step 2: x = 1
btn = button_ + 1
button_1.bg = {value}

Step 3: x = 2
btn = button_ + 2
button_2.bg = {value}
.
.
.
Step 30: x = 29
btn = button_ + 29
button_29.bg = {value}`

Comment: I apologize for the terrible comment. I tried to add line breaks to make it easy to read, but they were removed.